# Vertical aligning text

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to vertically align some text in a div whilst the text is under an image.

I'm not very good at explaining things but this is the code I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/c1249bd8/

HTML:

```
<div class="childContainer">
    <a href="#" class="childLink">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/500/500" alt="Test" class="childImg"/>
        <h1 class="childName">Testing</h1>
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .childContainer {
  /* Height and width */
  height: 10rem;
  width: 10rem;
  /* Hide overflow */
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Allows z-index */
  position: relative;
  /* Circle */
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.childLink {
  /* No default link styling */
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  /* All Bubble is link */
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  /* Circle */
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.childImg {
  /* Full Bubble */
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  /* On top of text */
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  /* Fade in/out stuff */
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .30s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .30s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .30s ease-in-out;
}

.childNameWrapper {
  vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300|Luckiest+Guy');
.childName {
  /* Behind Image */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  /* In Center */
  text-align: center;
  /* Nice handwriting font */
  font-family: 'Luckiest Guy', cursive;
}

.childImg:hover {
  /* Fade on hover */
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .30s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .30s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .30s ease-in-out;
}
```

Thanks,

Oscar.

Comment: where exactly do you want the text to be?

Comment: Hi Oscar, im really not sure what you're trying to achieve. You want the `<h1>` vertically aligned or below the image?

Comment: Just as it is in the fiddle but in the middle of the circle when the image fades out rather than how it is now.

Comment: it not in the center but you may look at this https://jsfiddle.net/c1249bd8/6/  setting width and height of the `h1` tag to inherit makes the text visible but not exactly in the centre..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **display flex**. It is quite easy and simple to use.

Check the [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/c1249bd8/9/).

```
.childLink {
    display:flex;
    align-items : center;
   /* No default link styling */
    color: #000;
    position:relative;
    text-decoration: none;
   /* All Bubble is link */
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   /* Circle */
  border-radius: 50%;
  //  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: Hey Oscar, fixed a small bug in that implementation. I have updated the FIDDLE link. Check it.

Answer (score 0):

change your 'childname' class to this:

```
    .childName {
  /* Behind Image */
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  line-height: 90px;
  /* In Center */
  text-align: center;
  /* Nice handwriting font */
  font-family: 'Luckiest Guy', cursive;
```

The trick here is the lineheight :)

Comment: My actual application is dynamic so some of the text may have multiple lines. But thanks anyway. :-)

Comment: It doesn't matter. just set the line-height to the container's width (or half of it). If it's too much text i suggest decreasing the font-size. Nevertheless the line-height works for vertical alignment

Comment: This also doesn't seem to be responsive though.

Comment: Not a feasible solution